# C arrays and C++ iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I have to do some image processing on a buffer stored as a C array.
The processing must be done symetrically relatively the the central column.

So I have to process all the left half from the center to the left edge, and all the right half from the center to the right edge. So, to scroll on horizontal axis, when processing the left half, I have to decrement the X coordinate (and so the pointer), and when processing the right half, I have to increment the X coordinate (and so the pointer).

I planned to do a function processing only a half, and to send as argument a forward or reverse iterator. But if I call `std::begin(myCArray)`, I get a raw pointer, and if I call `std::rbegin(myCArray)`, I get a `std::reverse_iterator`. I don't have common type, and I don't want to use template, because the function will be pretty heavy.

Should I create my own iterator ??

Comment: If you don't do a template, you need an iterator that can conditionally increment backwards, and that sounds worse to me than templating the function. If the template is too heavy to be in a header, you can move it to a .cpp and use explicit instantiation (since there are only two possible template arguments).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They want to type-erase forward and backward iteration over an array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what is done today, and a lot of code is duplicated just because some + need to be replaced by -.

Comment: Raw array seems irrelevant. `begin()` and `rbegin()` do not give the same type, anyway.

Comment: Why not use a template for the "iterator", which you can simply pass in any forward *or* reverse iterator, and its increment operation should go either forward or backward correctly any way. This is basically how any standard library algorithm function works. E.g. `template<typename It> void foo(It current, It end) { while (current < end) { /* Process *current */ ++current; } }`

Comment: The problem is not the function to advance (they already exist in the STL).
The problem is the nature of the arguments given to my function.

Comment: Ah I see, you need to go from the *center* and out toward the edges, not from the edges to the center. In that case yes you might need to implement your own iterator. Or two wrapper functions, one which loops forward and the other backward, and which then calls the main processing function. Yes there will be a couple of lines of code that''s very similar, but it's very simple and easy and maintainable. There's no need to complicate it too much.

Comment: There's no **minimal reproducible sample**. What is the prototype of C API function? The least you should provide here is the declaration of that function.

Comment: @Red.Wave There is no C API function. I am talking about C array.
Also, the querstion si about the arguments of the function, so I cannot give (yet) prototype.

Comment: @Oodini: you can give an actual prototype as `template <typename Iterator> void do_processing(It middle, It end)` and ask how to remove the template from that, for example.

Comment: Why would you use a C array then? If C++ is the inly party involved, forget about C arrays and raw pointers. And again, without enough context, every answer will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to not use iterator at all and just use loop with `int` increment:

```
// proccess all pixel from middle to edge (inclusive)
void do_processing(Pixel* middle, Pixel* edge)
{
    int increment = middle < edge ? 1 : -1;

    for (auto p = middle; p != edge; p += increment) {
        process(*p); // Current work on given pixel
    }
    // We cannot check (p != edge + increment) which would be UB when increment is negative
    // so process it outside of the loop
    process(*edge);
}
```

Comment: I think there's some UB in here. Consider if you have three iterators `begin, middle, end`. Then you can call `do_processing(begin, middle); do_processing(end, middle)`. However, that would result in dereferencing the one-past-the-end iterator in the second call during `process(*p)`. The user has to be pretty smart to avoid this footgun and to use this function correctly. Or, if we call `do_processing(middle, ...)` for each end, then `process(*p)` might process the center element twice.

Comment: As state in comment, pointers passed are **inclusive**, you should not pass `std::end(container)`. (and in that case, UB would happen in `process(*edge)`, not `process(*p)` ;) )

Comment: OP has to choose what should be done for the "middle" Pixel. BTW for even width, there would be 2 "middle", whereas for odd width, only one "middle".

Comment: For odd sizes, the "middle" pixel won't be processed.

Comment: @Oodini: so you have to pass correct/adjusted argument to above function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom iterator:

```cpp
pixel row[N];
pixel* begin = std::begin(row);
pixel* end = std::end(row);
pixel* middle = begin + (end - begin) / 2;

void process(pixel* begin, pixel* middle, pixel* end) {
    // note: the pixel index can always be computed with: it - begin
    for (auto i = begin; i != middle; ++i) {
        process_forward(*i);
    }
    for (auto j = end; j-- != middle; ) {
        process_reverse(*j);
    }
}
```

Of course, this is doing the work of `std::reverse_iterator` manually, but that is very simple in this case.

If you wanted a function that can accept both forward and reverse iterators, it would need to be a function template.

Comment: The OP seems to want to process out from the middle (going to the first element when decrementing, and to the last when incrementing).   This appears to be doing the opposite - moving in from the first and last elements, and finishing in the "middle".